# System fails to boot when providing `console` boot parameter to enable serial access

Tags: linux, debian, boot, serial-port, serial-console

## What I want to accomplish

I would like to have remote terminal access to my NAS (which runs Debian Stretch) via an USB-RS232 adapter. As this machine is supposed to be headless, I would also like to see the boot process on the serial line.

(Still, for the sake of assessing this problem, there is a screen connected on the HDMI port at the moment.)

## The actions I took

I appended `console=ttyUSB0` to the kernel argument list. When booting, this causes my system to freeze.

The last lines of boot output are: (Bootloader is extlinux)

```
Loading /vmlinuz... ok
Loading /initrd.img...ok
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok
```

When not using said kernel parameter the machine is booting without problems. From there on, I could accomplish serial terminal access easily by running

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
```

on the remote server, and

```
screen -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

on my local machine. Hence, the USB-RS232 adapters are working correctly. The server is a [Intel NUC 5CPYH](https://ark.intel.com/products/85254/Intel-NUC-Kit-NUC5CPYH) with Braswell chipset and runs a `Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64` debian kernel.

## My question

Which actions do I have to take to get it working?

### Edit № 1

When providing `console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0,9600n8` as boot parameters the machine boots just fine, but I still cannot connect to the serial port. Also, `systemctl status serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service` says that the service is `loaded` and `inactive (dead)`. I would have expected it to be up and running then.

### Edit № 2

I did a bit of research and found out that my initramfs was lacking the relevant kernel modules. I managed to enter the initramfs shell by providing `break=init` as kernel parameter and saw that there was no `/dev/ttyUSB0` device.

I added `cp210x`, `pl2303` and `ftdi_sio` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and, after recreating the initramfs, saw that now there is a `/dev/ttyUSB0` device in initramfs shell.

Still, I couldn't connect from my other machine.
So I tried to start getty on that device manually:

```
# /sbin/getty -L 9600 /dev/ttyUSB0 vt100
getty: setsid: Operation not permitted
# su root -c "/sbin/getty -L 9600 /dev/ttyUSB0 vt100"
sh: su: not found
```

So that's where I am now.

Comment: So sad to see motherboards without even a vestigial serial port these days. If you just want boot messages you might look at [netconsole](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole) instead, to get them over the ethernet.  Also, lots of articles say you need a kernel compiled with `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y` to get boot messages on usb, and this is not often the case as it still marked "experimental".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian currently does not build its Linux kernel with `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y`, which is required for this feature to work.

The corresponding bug report is https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868352

After building my own kernel with `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y` (see https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-official), I also had to include the FTDI serial driver for my adapter in the initrd:

```
# echo ftdi_sio >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
# update-initramfs -u
```

Finally, I adjusted `/etc/default/grub` to read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="panic=10 panic_on_oops=1 console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0,115200"
```

…and ran `update-grub`.

Afterwards, I successfully see the boot messages and can log in via the automatically starting serial-getty@ttyUSB0 service.

Comment: Unable to test, but sounds very reasonable. Plus, the author used to be involved in the Debian project. Thus, accepting it as correct answer for now.

Answer (score 3):

Your system is not freezing. You just directed **ALL** your output to the serial console.

Passing console arguments to the kernel, you have got to include both the local console and the serial interface.

See [TLDP - Remote Serial Console HOWTO - Chapter 5. Configure Linux kernel](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel.html)

> Figure 5-2. Recommended kernel parameters, **PCs with video card**
>
> ```
> console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8
> ```
>
> Kernel messages will appear on both the first virtual terminal and the
>   serial port. Messages from the init system and the system logger will
>   appear only on the first serial port. This can be slightly confusing
>   when looking at the attached monitor: the machine will appear to boot
>   and then hang. Don't panic, the init system has started but is now
>   printing messages to the serial port but is printing nothing to the
>   screen. If a getty has been configured then a login: prompt will
>   eventually appear on the attached monitor.
>
> For PCs without a video card, this HOWTO suggests the kernel
>   parameters:
>
> Figure 5-3. Recommended kernel parameters, **PCs without video card**
>
> ```
> console=ttyS0,9600n8
> ```
>
> These parameters are passed to the booting kernel by the boot loader.
>   Next we will configure the boot loader used by your Linux installation
>   to pass the console parameters to the kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either. I edited my questions with the results of your suggestion. This was a very valid concern though, hence I upvoted your answer.

Comment: what did not work? When I setup this in kernel, I had also to start the service afterwards for serial to work.

Comment: I could not see boot output on the other machine which was connected over the serial line. Also, the [blog page](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html) of the `systemd` author suggests that starting the service manually should not be necessary when using the `console` boot parameter: `TL;DR: To make use of a serial console, just use console=ttyS0 on the kernel command line, and systemd will automatically start a getty on it for you.`